# How to change positions of html elements with only using css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a wordpress and working with a theme. The theme host does not let me insert html directly into the files or let me use ftp. The only way I can do this is by using CSS. I am trying to make it so that a slideshow is at the very top of the page. The theme by default makes the website logo appear at the top which i don't want.

Here is the html

```
  <div id="page" class="site">
     <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
     </header>
     <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
           <article id="post-2" class="post-2">
              <header class="entry-header">
                 <h1>hello</h1>
              </header>
              <div class="entry-content">
                 <div class="metaslider">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </article>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I need to make it so that the div with class `metaslider` comes before everything else in the page. More specifically, `metaslider` comes before the `masthead` header element. I tried using `position: realtive; top: -500px;` but it just overlaps the logo which is not what i want, i want to push the `masthead` down and put `metaslider` on top of it.

Comment: [This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) about positioning might help you

Comment: Are you able to install plugins or access this section <YOUR-WEBSITE-URL-HERE>/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?

Comment: Yes. But i am not able to save changes since it says `You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Let me know if this does work

Comment: it just pushed the page down a bit.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want! Can you explain more!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following style information and the metaslider div was moved to the top for me.

```
.entry-header {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 220px;
}
.metaslider {
    background: rebeccapurple;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Please note that since I made the metaslider absolute, I had to give it a width and height to compensate for empty content and the case may very well vary for you.

To test for the rest of the content I replicated the entry-header as entry-body and all seems to be aligned well so far.

Here is my updated HTML and CSS:

```
<style>
  .entry-header {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 220px;
  }
  .metaslider {
      background: rebeccapurple;
      height: 200px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
  }
</style>
<div id="page" class="site">
  <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  </header>
  <div id="content" class="site-content">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
      <article id="post-2" class="post-2">
        <header class="entry-header">
          <h1>hello</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="entry-content">
          <div class="metaslider">
          </div>
          <header class="entry-body">
            <h1>hi</h1>
          </header>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```